# Xamarin Forms iOS Local Notifications not displaying

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm building an application in Xamarin.Forms, and am having trouble getting the Local Notifications to display in iOS.
I've followed the guide from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications/ and the notification still doesnt display.
I've added the following to my FinishedLaunching method in AppDelegate:

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization (UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert, (approved, err) => {});
```

And in my page where I'd like the notification to display:

```
using UserNotifications;


var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent ();
content.Title = "Notification Title";
content.Subtitle = "Notification Subtitle";
content.Body = "Test Notification.";
content.Badge = 1;

var trigger =  UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger (5, false);

var requestID = "sampleRequest";
var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier (requestID, content, 
trigger);

UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest (request, (err) => {
if (err != null) {
    // Do something with error...
}
});
```

All of my nuGet packages are up to date, and I've tried testing on both iOS iPhone simulators, and a physical iPad device.

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, if your app is in the foreground, the iOS system will silence notifications by default.

**Solutions:**

There're two solutions for you:

1. Go to the background via clicking the Home button, when you trigger the delayed notification. Then the notification will show up.
2. Implement the delegate [userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter), it will be called when there's a notification arrives in your app when it is in the foreground.
   For example, here's the code snippet for enabling the notification when the app is in the foreground:

   ```
   UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new MyNotificationDelegate();

   public class MyNotificationDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
   {
       public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification,  Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
       {
           completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! implementing the delegate willPresentNotification solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that : )

Comment: so the OP code to send local notification isn't needed anymore, hm

Answer (score 3):

aaaargh! This is the crucial information which I have been mis-understanding for 2 days. The Xamarin example has a button on the app which fires a local notification.

This gets ignored since the app (with the button on it) is in the foreground when you press the button!

Comment: Yes. Lot's of example code out there is 'excellent'. LOL